# C++17: Difference in pointer storage between unique_ptr<char[]> and shared_ptr<char[]>

Tags: c++, stl, shared-ptr, c++17, unique-ptr

I am getting confused with:

```
unique_ptr<char[]> u_ptr = make_unique<char[]>(10);
sprint(u_ptr.get(), 10, "milos"); // get returns char*
cout << u_ptr.get(); // get returns char*
```

And:

```
shared_ptr<char[]> s_ptr = make_shared<char[]>(10);
sprint(*s_ptr.get(), 10, "milos"); // get here returns char** ?
cout << *s_ptr.get(); // get here returns char** ?
```

So, while `unique_ptr<char[]>` returns `char*` for the underlying array, `shared_ptr<char[]>` seems to return `char(*)[]` pointer to array pointer?
I made few tests and I could use `shared_ptr<char>` with default delete:

```
shared_ptr<char> s_ptr(new char[10], default_delete<char[]>());
sprint(s_ptr.get(), 10, "milos"); // get here returns char*, fine
cout << s_ptr.get(); // same here
```

But I'm guessing the idea behind C++17 is not the approach with `shared_ptr<char>` and custom specified deleter: `default_delete<char[]>` cause this was possible prior to C++17.

Can someone clarify correct usage, and why does following occurs:

```
unique_ptr<int> u = make_unique<int>(5);
auto iu = u.get(); // iu is typeof int*
```

at the same time

```
unique_ptr<int[]> ua = make_unique<int[]>(5);
auto iua = ua.get(); // iua is still typeof int* ?
```

While for shared_ptr:

```
shared_ptr<int> s = make_shared<int>(5);
auto is = s.get(); // is is typeof int*
```

but

```
shared_ptr<int[]> sa = make_shared<int[]>(5);
auto isa = sa.get(); // isa is typeof int** ???
```

.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` has a specific specialisation for when T is an array type. This causes the correct default deleter to be selected.

For better or worse, `std::shared_ptr` does not (while `std::make_shared` does as of c++20).

The behaviour you see in `shared_ptr`, returning a T** as a result of calling get() is an anomaly which has been fixed in c++17 (it will now return T*).

This is because until c++17, `std::shared_ptr::element_type` was `T` and `std::shared_ptr::get` returned a `T*`.

As of c++17 `element_type` is defined to be `std::remove_extent_t<T>` and `get()` returns `element_type*`;

so given `using SAI = std::shared_ptr<int[]>`

in c++14:

`SAI::element_type = int[]`

`SAI::get() -> (int[])*` which decays to `int**`

in c++17:

`SAI::element_type = int`

`SAI::get() -> int*`

Documentation links for reference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

As far as I am aware, the way to create a shared array prior to c++17 would be something like this:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto uai = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
    std::shared_ptr<int> sai { uai.release(), uai.get_deleter() };
}
```

and after c++17:

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int[]> sai = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
}
```

Comment: I guess the difference is specified on MSDN here (shared_ptr): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/shared-ptr-class#get
"Gets address of owned resource" so it makes sense that it'll be `char(*)[]` for `shared_ptr<char[]>` And here (unique_ptr): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/unique-ptr-class#get
"Returns stored_ptr". So also make sense it'll be `char*` for `unique_ptr<char[]>` One more thing: MSDN specifies: `<class T, class D>
class unique_ptr<T[], D>` while shared_ptr doesn't have this. Though unclear why the difference..

Comment: @MilošLjumović shared_ptr is fundamentally different from unique_ptr in a number of ways, for example the ability to share lifetime while pointing at different parts of the object. However the lack of a T[] version of make_shared until c++17 was certainly an oversight.